# how to gst-rtsp-server authentication IP or tested username?

Tags: authentication, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm using gst-rtsp-server authentication to implement a RTSP stream server, I want to log where(such as IP address) and who view the RTSP stream. How can I achieve this? Does anyone who familiar with gst-rtsp-server can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like we can use specify a plugin to output authenticated IP or username and etc.  Hope it can help someone who using Gstreamer.

```sh
GST_DEBUG=rtspauth,rtspclient:6 ./gstreamer_app
```